# Django admin action with intermediate page: not getting info back

Tags: python, django, action

I'm trying to create an admin action that adds a custom time delta to some date. The time delta will be read from a input in the intermediate page. After confirming it, I will apply that delta to every instance selected previously. Using this code (I simplified for this question) I can't get the value of the entered time delta. I can't tell whether the user pressed the "Apply" button.

models.py

```
class Match(models.Model):
    date_of_match=models.DateTimeField()
```

admin.py

```
class MatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions=('move_date',)
def move_date(self,request,queryset):
    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        #to do, add timedelta to date_of_match
        print("I'M IN!")
    return render(request.'admin/move_date.html',{'matches':queryset})
move_date.short_description="Move date"
```

move_date.html

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>How much delta?<p>
    <input type="number" step="1" value="days"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="move_date" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Apply"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin , but after selecting my action in the drop-down menu, I want the user to input a number, and then, using that number, complete the action.

Answer (score 5):

Probably too late to help OP, but I came across this question when having the same issue and it was not immediately obvious looking elsewhere what was going on.

When the `changelist_view` is processed (the view we are `POST`ing to) it looks in `request.POST` for a specific key: `_selected_action` which is defined in `django.contrib.admin.helpers` as `ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME`. I used the delete action that is built into the admin for reference, and it uses it this way in the template:

```
{% for obj in queryset %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}">
{% endfor %}
```

then in your context you just need to:

```py
context = {
    'queryset': queryset,  # method param
    'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
}
```

Now your method gets called again when you `POST` your form, and you can detect/handle the `POST` as you're trying to do here. (You want to return `None` from the block that handles your `POST` data so the view knows to go back to the list view.)