# Why won't this intermediate Django page get back to the former action?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

This is Django 1.11.29. I'm trying to write a simple Django admin action with an intermediate page. I've seen something similar has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845346/django-admin-action-with-intermediate-page-not-getting-info-back) but even following the response advice I can't manage to solve it.

In my `ModelAdmin` I have this:

```
from django.contrib.admin import helpers
from django.shortcuts import render

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = ['send_email']
    ...
```

I implemented my `send_email` action like this:

```
def send_email(self, request, queryset):
    print(request.POST)
    print(queryset)
    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        # Do some stuff
    else:
        return render(request, 'admin/confirm_email.html', { 'mymodels': queryset, 'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME })
```

This is pretty standard according to the Django documentation.

The `admin/confirm_email.html` looks like this:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>You\'re about to send a lot of mails!</p>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for mymodel in mymodels %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ mymodel.pk }}" />
    {% endfor %}

    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="history.go(-1); return true;" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Confirm" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that when the admin action is invoked, it enters the intermediate page, but when the <kbd>Confirm</kbd> button is hit, it won't call the admin action back, so I cannot process the answer. It just shows a text stating "No action selected" on the admin page.

So why is not the `send_email()` method called again when the <kbd>Confirm</kbd> button is hit? I've seen several similar examples and all of them seem to work, I can't figure out why this one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I forgot to reference the admin action in the form. Adding the following statement in the form made the difference:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_email" />
```